# How to calculate the sum of the squared deviations from the mean if you add one extra known element?

Tags: statistics

I have a sample, denoted as $\underset{\sim}{x}$, of seven elements and I know the mean is 130. If I remove element $a=235$, the new sample $\underset{\sim}{y}$, has a mean of 112.5. I also know that $SS_y = 7.5$ and I want to find $SS_x$.

Where $\displaystyle SS_x = \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(x_i-\overline{x})^2}_{\color{red}1} = \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 - n\overline{x}^2}_{\color{red}2}$

I tried it like this, using $\color{red}2$:

\begin{split}
SS_x &= \sum_{i=1}^7 x_i^2 - 7\times 130^2 \\
&= \sum_{i=1}^6 x_i^2 + 235^2 - 7\times 130^2 \\
&= \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^6 x_i^2 -6\times 112.5^2}_{SS_y} + 6\times 112.5^2 + 235^2 - 7\times 130^2 \\
&= 7.5 + 6\times 112.5^2 + 235^2 - 7\times 130^2
\end{split}

But it's a multiple choice problem and the options are 6, 7.5,45 and 52.5 and all are far from what I get.